# Ctrl + Alt + Del on a Mac with Windows

Tags: windows-7, laptop, macbook, boot-camp, osx-leopard

I'm using Boot Camp to run Windows on my Mac.

Last night I tried to compress the memory of C, then after that finished, it told me to

> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to restart

How do I press these keys?

Comment: this question is > 5 years old and still has no validated answer. could please someone confirm what works here?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Backspace (without Fn) seems to work for me on my MacBook Pro, as (roughly) per FDinoff's answer.  Not sure how that works exactly - maybe there's some specific logic to handle that case.

Comment: I just today installed Windows 10 using Bootcamp on a 2012 MBRP 15" running OSX 10.13.6, and found that both key combos in FDinoff's answer work for me.

Answer (score 6):

One of these should work. <kbd>Option</kbd> is <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Windows. Your <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key generates <kbd>Delete</kbd> (You might need to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to generate Delete)

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Or

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Comment: Should the key combinations say "Backspace" instead of "Delete"?  If there were a Delete key, that would probably just work!

Comment: This one one of several confused answers. Backspace & Delete are two separate keys unless you have a short keyboard, in which case you use Fn/Backspace to mimic Delete. Backspace alone **never** generates Delete.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: It's similar in that it also opens Task Manager like C-A-D sometimes does. But it won't work in the other situations, where C-A-D specifically is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative. This worked for me in a slightly different and more complicated setup (connecting from a Mac to a Linux server through SSH and then from the Linux server to a Windows Server 2016 server through Remote desktop protocol using the `rdesktop` Linux RDP command line client).

In Windows:

1. Click Start menu
2. Click in the search bar
3. Type "powershell"
4. In the search results, click "powershell.exe"
5. In the PowerShell shell that opens, type the following:

   ```
   Powershell -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -command "(new-object -ComObject shell.application).WindowsSecurity()"
   ```

If PowerShell is not available, instead search for "cmd.exe" and in the cmd prompt, type:

```
explorer shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Taken from: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9c2ea402-087a-40a0-83de-170b49fdaac5/how-to-change-password-in-rdp-session?forum=winserverTS

Note: if your Mac keyboard layout is not English US, it might be hard to get the `{`, `}` characters in cmd.exe. In that case try the following:

- Change you keyboard layout on your Mac to English US (use System Preferences)
- In X11's preferences, check "Use system keyboard layout"
- In Windows, make sure to also set the keyboard layout to English US.

Comment: These don’t work in the trivial setup of a single, non-Mac computer, with a user at the keyboard.   So I would be surprised if they work on Mac.

Comment: well... it does works for me :)

Comment: The reason it does not work on a "single, non-Mac computer, with a user at the keyboard" is because it only works from a Windows Terminal Server, as [noted here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windowssecurity#remarks) :)

Answer (score 1):

To press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> on a macOS machine, <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> will not work.
You will need to press <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> to get it to work.
the <kbd>delete</kbd> key on macOS is backspace, and <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> is the real delete.

Comment: This is one of several confused answers. "the delete key on macOS is backspace" No it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers here are confused.
The reason there is so much confusion is that many people who have only ever owned Macbooks & others with short keyboards may be unaware that an extended keyboard has both true Delete and Backspace keys, whereas a short keyboard only has a Backspace key.
Windows wants the 'true' Delete key.

[image]

### Pressing Fn Backspace will send 'true' Delete.

So on an extended keyboard  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd> is the correct method.
On a short keyboard you need to press  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd> 
The Fn Backspace method will also work on an extended keyboard if you really feel the need.

*Note:*
Opt == Alt in all cases.
Some Mac keyboards actually say Alt, some say Opt & some only have the symbol ⌥.
It's all the same key.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use one of the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: Only if your keyboard has a 'Del' key in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Bootcamp Windows Partition.
I tried 'every combination' that I found and none of them worked when I tried to log in to Windows. I solved this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> problem by plugging a PC keyboard in to the Macbook. Worked like a champ! Be sure to change that "user must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd>" setting in User Accounts once you are in!

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer to the proposed question.

Comment: It looks like a workaround to me - plug in a PC keyboard.