# How to press Ctrl/Alt/Del on Macbook with no Delete key?

Tags: windows-7

Entering the Windows 7 screen on the MacBook shows the press control+ Alt + Delete to log on. I press the buttons but to no avail

Comment: Macbooks don't have a Delete key. Try Ctrl/Alt/Fn/Backspace

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1667431/347380